# I can not add 'č' 'ř' 'ě'

Tags: mysql, sql, heidisql

I use HeidiSQL. I am unable add to my database characters with diacritics such as `č`, `ř` or `ě`.

For example, when I try add a character `č`, the following error occurs:

```
Incorrect string value: '\xC4\x8D\' for column 'name' at row 1.
```

What I can do?

Column type is `varchar`. I think that this could be a problem with the coding, but I'm not sure.

Here's the coding of my database:

[image]

Comment: What is the datatype of that column? It should probably be `nvarchar`

Comment: I edited datatype, but I dont know what you think with "correct database type"

Comment: Do you think "mysql"?

Comment: @JirkaLuňák There are many different database engines that use their own type of SQL, such as MySQL, MSSQL, NoSQL, etc. It seems that you're using MySQL (due to the [tag:heidisql] tag you used), so I've edited your question to add that in.

Comment: If you are using UTF8 try to use latin1 (cp1252). This could fit better for your language

Comment: @Michael I am not sure, where I can setting this... What should I have on row 3 and what on row 4?

Comment: That seems to be the "Bulk table editor" dialogue. It's totally unrelated to your table settings. You need to click on a table name in the **main window** and check the "Table" tab.

Comment: @Michael That'd would be a bad move. UTF-8 supports the complete Unicode catalogue. Latin-1 only supports 256 Western Europe characters and `č` is used in Eastern Europe.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález https://ctrlv.cz/1obp this?

Comment: That's exactly the same dialogue. Your copy of HeidiSQL appears to be in Czech. Can you speak Czech? Do you need to help to switch to English?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I speak Czech

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález https://ctrlv.cz/rspF this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using UTF-8 and Latin-1 (which in MySQL is actually Windows-1252) in the same application. The first one is a fully Unicode compatible encoding but the second one can only store a very limited range of characters used in Western European languages. You simply cannot store Czech in the `name` column if it happens to use `latin1_swedish_ci` as `url` does.

[image: Create table]

We are in 2018. Use UTF-8 everywhere.